# Best practices for sharing scrips across proxy bundles

Tags: apigee

I would like to reuse some JavaScript resources across my API proxy bundles.  But of course I would like to think about what the best practices for accomplishing this first.

For example given the policy:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Javascript async="false" continueOnError="false" enabled="true" timeLimit="200" name="script-trafficmanagementvars">
    <DisplayName>Script-TrafficManagementVars</DisplayName>
    <FaultRules/>
    <Properties/>
    <IncludeURL>jsc://Script-FunctionLibrary.js</IncludeURL>
    <IncludeURL>jsc://Script-ErrorHandling.js</IncludeURL>
    <ResourceURL>jsc://Script-TrafficManagementVars.js</ResourceURL>
</Javascript>
```

The following scripts are used across multiple proxies.

```
Script-FunctionLibrary.js
Script-ErrorHandling.js
```

While this one is specific to be a Proxy:

```
Script-TrafficManagementVars.js
```

I'd like your comment on the best practice for doing this.

I'm concerned about this approach because it builds dependencies across proxies.  However I'm noticing opportunities for shared artifacts across proxies.

Quick note:

I deploy my proxies using a maven build pack (4G-gateway-maven-build-pack).

Thanks

Comment: Could you add a little color to your question by explaining what your primary concerns are for reused JS? Is versioning an issue? convenience? speed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check out [Resources](http://apigee.com/docs/gateway-services/content/resource-files), which allows you to share resources across environments or organizations. Doing this will give you the added benefit of shorter deploy times.

Answer (score 0):

All JavaScript files available across an Org are stored under:

`/organizations/{org_name}/resourcefiles/jsc`

JavaScript files stored in the `/organizations` collection are available to all the API proxies running in any environment.